# add word in url using .httaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd

Right now i am accessing abc.xml from test directory as below

```
http://localhost/test/abc.xml
```

I want to redirect the above url as below

```
http://localhost/test/test.php?abc.xml
http://localhost/test/test.php?abc.js
http://localhost/test/test.php?xyz.txt
```

if i access any file from test directory ,it will be accessible by appending test.php? to the file name .

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You should attempt to research your question instead of simply farming out your work to SF.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/test/abc.xml$ /test/test.php?abc.xml [NC,L]
```

Comment: sorry , i don't have the test.php file in the test directory .but test.php? sholud come in the URL. By using the your code it not redirecting ,when i modified the url as required, it is asking test.php file in test directory.

Comment: now i placed test.php file in test directory .Now i am able to access test.php file.but i need to access abc.xml